# Eclipse chokes on enum, even though Compiler compliance level is 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, java-6

I have set my Eclipse project's `Compiler compliance level` to 1.6

But I get errors like in the screenshot below: `Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5`.

I have refreshed/cleaned/restarted Eclipse at least 10 times.
It compiles fine with Maven2. The Eclipse project has been generated by Maven2.
The project uses java-6-openjdk

[image]

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? By "cleaning" do you mean blowing away the project file? What about metadata? are you sure the error description is the one for the enum? Something may be out-of-sync, because there aren't any annotations there.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Eclipse Helios-SR2. By cleaning, I meant "Project>Clean". The error for the enum is `Syntax error on token "enum", interface expected`, in the screenshot I scrolled to show another error that I thought would be more interesting. The annotation is actually in another class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Other solution:

1) Set Workspace JRE to 1.5 (and apply/save). Projects will rebuild.

2) Set Workspace JRE back to 1.6 (and apply/save). Projects will rebuild.

All errors are then gone.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the Eclipse project and re-importing it solved the problem.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck Enable project specific settings , click apply. Eclipse will ask for a build , click ok . Errors will be gone after the build .

Also , add the following in your pom.xml

```
`<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`